# Getting a post variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a case where I want to  pass  a variable inside a function. 
The code gives more clarity:

```
<?php

$id=$_POST['id'];            

echo "
<script type=\"text/javascript\">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    function loadData(page){
      $.ajax({  
        type: \"POST\",
        url: \"loadSubscritor.php\",
        dataType: \"html\",
        data: ({  page:page }),
        success: function(msg) {
          $(\"#subscritor #container\").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
            $(\"#subscritor #container\").html(msg);
          });
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('alertErr');
        }
      });
    }

    loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
    $('#subscritor #container .pagination li.active').live('click',function() {
      var page = $(this).attr('p');
      loadData(page);
    });           

    $('#subscritor #go_bt').live('click',function() {
      var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
      var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
      if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
        loadData(page);
      }else{
        alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
        $('.goto').val(\"\").focus();
        return false;
      }
    });
  }); 
</script>                 
<h3>Subscritor</h3>     

<div id=\"subscritor\">
  <div id=\"container\">
        <div class=\"pagination\"></div>
  </div> 
</div>"; 

?>
```

As shown in the code,
I would like to know how could I pass $id inside the loadData(page) function .
I get this variable from a post request made with ajax, and need to use it inside the function to pass it has variable to loadSubscritor.php

Any idea on how to do it?

EDIT 1: I guees I wasnt very clear on what I wanted, i want to do this :
     function loadData(page){
          $.ajax({
            data: ({  page:page  id:$id   }),

Thanks in advance.

Comment: pass two parameters in your function

Comment: where do you need to use the variable `$id`

Comment: If you want to write your PHP variable into the JS code you're echoing, you can do it by concatenating it like this: `echo "...code... loadData(" . $id . "); ...code...";`

Comment: @RafaelShkembi can you give me an example.

Comment: @ravishankar I want it inside loadData function

Comment: @blex didnt understand what you did there

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understood what you are trying to achieve you could replace this :

```
$id=$_POST['id'];
```

By this :

```
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : 1;
```

And this :

```
loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
```

By this :

```
loadData($id);
```

For explanation, if it's first time page load, $id will be set to "1".
Else, this will come from $_POST['id'].

Comment: I want the $id as in loadData(page,$id)

Comment: Like replacing :  data: ({  page:page })  by :  data: ({  page:page, id: $id })  ?

Comment: yes that, can I just do that and call loadData(page,id) ?

Comment: Yes, if you are sure that you want your $id to be the same for this whole page

Answer (score 0):

Inside your jquery code you can call a php variable in following way

```
var current_page = "<?php echo $id; ?>" ;
```

Comment: so, if I do loadData(page, current_page) it will have two parameters  and the current_page is the one that I want to use?

Answer (score -1):

You can make a local variable and easily use as below:

```
<?php

 $id=$_POST['id'];            


  echo " 


        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        var id = \"".$id."\";
         $(document).ready(function(){
            function loadData(page){
                $.ajax
                ({  
                     type: \"POST\",
                    url: \"loadSubscritor.php\",
                                         dataType: \"html\",

                   data: ({  page:page
                             }),
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $(\"#subscritor #container\").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                        {
                            $(\"#subscritor #container\").html(msg);
                        });
                    },
                        error:
         function() 
         {               alert('alertErr');




        }



                });
            }
            loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
            $('#subscritor #container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                var page = $(this).attr('p');
                loadData(id);

            });           
            $('#subscritor #go_bt').live('click',function(){
                var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                    loadData(id);
                }else{
                    alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                    $('.goto').val(\"\").focus();
                    return false;
                }

            });
        });    
   </script>                 
<h3>Subscritor</h3>     

<div id=\"subscritor\">
<div id=\"container\">
        <div class=\"pagination\"></div>
  </div> 
  </div>



                ";                                                                                                                                                                          
?>
```